# Can this device really handle 250V x 16A

Tags: power, relay

I have the following relay device for DIN rail.

[image]

[image]

It contains HF115FK 12-Z3T relay inside. Manual says it can handle 220V and 16A.

Can this be true? Can I connect 3 kW heater to these thin PCB roads?

Comment: Thermally yes.. but those traces without insulation and little clearence worry me a little from a safety point of view. So better make sure, noone can access that relay and potentially touch it, and that no dust can get to it to short the traces and start a fire.

Comment: that terminal doesn't look good for that much current. The relay itself is right on the max rating, which is poor design; you should build in at least 33% extra, and even double isn't uncommon.

Comment: Handling 16 briefly yes, Handling it indefinitely, no. Link to the product data sheet.

Comment: I suppose the maufacturer has given ratings for the whole device, so do you have a manual for it? The relay is rated up to 16A and 250VAC but not at the same time, as maximum resistive load is 3kW. Who knows how the green terminals are rated, but at least some manufacturers do have 16A or 20A models available. PCB traces are not that long but I will leave others to estimate the ampacity of solder reinforced copper traces.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stay safe (as @tobalt pointed out), especially for moisture in the long term, put some kind of conformal coating on them: clean with solvent, dry the PCB and as coating you can even use some epoxy if you do not have specific products.

The relay: nominally 16A, but ...

- which load? (inductive I mean, such as AC11 and so on),
- which max environment temperature?
- how many operations are granted as expected life?

These are the most relevant factor behind the "16 A".

If you put a heater then it should be resistive almost (no problem). Number of operations however may be large.

The relay manufacturer is Hongfa. The [datasheet](https://www.tme.eu/Document/3d33df3cf28d6a9fe76477e0e11f02ea/HF115FK.pdf) does not say anything about the factors above: 100 mohm contact resistance (quite large, you see ... it's a maximum value without much added value). But ...

yours is model 12-Z3T as VDE approved for 16A-250V at 85 deg. Not bad, then.

General sizing:

- the relay is not abundant but should fit, because behind  VDE approval there are margins; the number of operations still is  bit troublesome;
- the green terminals have pin spacing of 5 mm (see by scaling to the relay contact spacing, that is 7.56 mm from datasheet); usually this type is rated also around 16A, and should be safe to working voltages of 400 Vac.

So connecting  13A load (3kW heater) is a bit on the edge of specs, but should work. If the heater does not work at 3 kW all the time, or if it can be reduced unless when really you need 3 kW that would be better for durability.